# Is it mathematically right to convert triangle it to such a circle like that?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

> [image]
>
> Given that
>
> $$\hat{ABC} = 26^\circ, \hat{ACB} = 52^\circ, |AC| = 11, [AB] \perp [AD]   $$
>
> Evaluate $|BD| = x $.

I want to change my point of view against these type of questions. What if we consider that this is a circle? Below I drew a diagram

[image]

Is it mathematically right to convert triangle it to such a circle like that? If yes, how can we take it from there?

Regards

Comment: You can draw a circle around triangle any time, but it does not necesery lead you to the solution.

Comment: I would use the word "inscribe" and not "convert" (i.e. inscribe the triangle in the circle). While there isn't anything wrong with it, does it really help you get to a solution? My guess would be no, but always open to new ideas.

Comment: Hints: What are the internal angles of a triangle? What's the sum of angles in a straight line?

Comment: Oh so, instead of directly solving the question, I need your dear assistance to change my perspective because I'm really having issues whenever I attempt to solve a question in triangles. For instance, doing what would make the question clear? I also found all angles.

Comment: Another hint: Do you know any theorems from trigonometry that tell you how a triangles sides relate to its angles?

Comment: The circle's unlikely to help you solve the problem.

Comment: @Jam Sure thing! I know Sine's theorem which states that $\dfrac{a}{\sin A} = \dfrac{b}{\sin A} = \dfrac{c}{\sin C}$. However, I'm also looking for strategy/method that makes it more clear than it is in this situtation.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you stuck and you want to know what to do next? Or do you want a better strategy than the law of sines?

Comment: @Jam It is obvious that I'm stuck. I, however, also stated that I'm having issues while solving a question in triangles. Thereby, I've been looking for a strategy that can be applied on other questions, it is sufficient if it just makes it clear. "I just want to realize what to realize"

Comment: @Enzo Ah, I see. Well I'm sure you can figure out all of the angles in your triangles fairly easily. After that, you could do the sine law on the triangle $ACD$, then do it a second time, on $ABD$, to find $x$. If you get stuck applying the sine law, draw each triangle $ACD$ or $ABD$ separately and think about what the edges and angles are.

Comment: @Jam Could you provide an answer that explains these things? I'm not familiar with Sine's law. So, I dont know how to apply it on each triangle.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to use the sine law, to get $x$ we need to look at triangle $BAD$. $$\frac x{\sin 90^\circ}=\frac{AD}{\sin 26^\circ}$$
We don't know $AD$, but we can once again apply the sine law in the $DAC$ triangle. $$\frac{AD}{\sin 52^\circ}=\frac{AC}{\sin \angle{ADC}}$$
You know $AC=11$ and you can get the angle $\angle ADC$ since it's a supplement of $\angle ADB$, and you know all angles in that triangle.

Comment: From $\frac{AD}{\sin 52^\circ}=\dfrac{AC}{\sin \angle{ADC}}$, do we get that $\dfrac{AD}{\sin 52^\circ}=\dfrac{11}{\sin 116^\circ}$?

Comment: No. What's the $ADC$ angle? If you know it, you can get $AD$.

Comment: Isn't it  $\hat{ADC} = 116$?

Comment: Correct. Now find $AD$ from my second equation. Then use it in the first equation, to find $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing $\angle ABD$ and $\angle BAD$ you can solve for $\angle ADB$ $$\angle ADB=180°-26°-90°=64°$$ The angles $\angle ADB$ and $\angle ADC$ are supplementary, so $\angle ADC=116°$. Knowing angles $\angle ADC, \angle ACD$, and the length of $AC$, the law of sines can be used to solve for the length of $AD$. 
$$\frac{11}{sin(116)}=\frac{AD}{sin(52)}\Rightarrow  AD=\frac{11sin(52)}{sin(116)}\approx9,64$$  The law of sines can be used again to find $x$. $$\frac{9.64}{sin(26)}=\frac{x}{sin(90)}\rightarrow x=\frac{9.64sin(90)}{sin(26)}$$ $x$ is 22.

That is how I would do it. Sorry about the format, I am not familiar with the equation makers.